# Table goes out of the border

Tags: tables, margins, border

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[htb!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Material model parameters for the FeFEHM components}
    \label{table:T1}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c cccccc}

        \hline        
      \textbf{Component} & \textbf{Authors} & \textbf{Formulation} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Parameters}}  \\ \hline
      
      & & & $\mu$ [kPA] & $g_1$ [-] & $g_2$ [-] & $\tau_1$ [s] & $\tau_2$ [s] & $\rho$ \\ \hline
   
      WM (CR) & & & 7.63 & 0.57 & 0.22 & 0.020 & 0.31 & 1041 \\
      GM (OC) & Menichetti & Visco-hyperelastic & 5.06 & 0.50 & 0.20 & 0.015 & 0.30 & 1045 \\
      CC & \textit{et al}. \cite{Menichetti2020} & & 4.49 & 0.57 & 0.22 & 0.021 & 0.30 & 1041 \\
      CB & & & 3.40 & 0.52 & 0.20 & 0.018 & 0.33 & 1045\\
      \hline
      & & & Young's Modulus [kPa] & Poisson's ratio [-] & $\rho$ \\
      \hline
      PG & Bouchonville \textit{et al}. \cite{Bouchonville2016} & Linear elastic & 9.5 & 0.45 & 1041 \\ \hline
      & & & $C_1_0$ [MPa] & $C_0_1$ [MPa] & $D_1$ $[MPa^-1]$ & $\rho$
      \\ \hline
      CSF & Gilchrist \textit{et al}. \cite{Gilchrist2003} & Hyperelastic & 0.9 & 1 & 0.9 & 1007
      \\ \hline
      Skull & & Rigid & & & 1908
      \\ \hline
      
      
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

However, it goes out of the border, like this:

[image]

Any ideas how I could make it work?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Hard to say if you don't share the code we'd need to reproduce the issue, but you could turn the table using `sidewaystable` from the `rotating` package.